# Get list items by checking priority of another list using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to implement something,

I have an item list with different priorities and I need to select the items based on these priorities. For that, I have another list of priorities. If priority "one" does not match it should check the second priority and so on. This can be checked with a simple foreach loop and check with .Any() function. But I'm wondering this can be done with a single LINQ query.

```
enum Brand
{
   Nike,
   Adidas,
   Levis
}
class Info
{
   public Brand Brand { get; set; }
   public int Status{ get; set; }
   public int Group{ get; set; }
}

var list = new Info[]
{
  new Info{Brand = Brand.Nike, Status = 0, Group = "C"},
  new Info{Brand = Brand.Adidas, Status = 0, Group = "D"},
  new Info{Brand = Brand.Nike, Status = 4, Group = "A"},
  new Info{Brand = Brand.Levis, Status = 0, Group = "B"},
  new Info{Brand = Brand.Adidas, Status = 5, Group = "B"}
};
List<string> groupPririties = new List<string>() { "B", "D", "A", "E" };
```

According to this item list and priority list, I should get Levis and Addidas only. But if those two are not on the list it should return Adidas item and so on. If I dont have any priority matching items in my list, it should return null.

Can I acheive this with linq query only?

Comment: I accidentally deleted a comment. Sorry about that. If I use orderBy and IndexOf it will give me a full result list. But what I want is, if the list has "B" items it should return all the "B" group items and nothing else. If priority match with "A" it should retun all the "A" items. But with Orderby() I get a full ordered list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'm wondering this can be done with a single LINQ query

```
var priorityItems = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.Group)
    .Where(grp => groupPririties.Contains(grp.Key))
    .OrderBy(grp => groupPririties.IndexOf(grp.Key))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```